# Using TensorFlow in R for solving equation

Tags: r, tensorflow, neural-network, rstudio, equation-solving

I am working on learning to solve equations in R and I am interested in doing it through TensorFlow (I already know how to do it using GA and Simulated Annealing). I am beginning with a simple equation: Y = X + Z, where X and Y are known and Z is to be estimated. This can be easily done in python, see this [blog](https://medium.com/@liccowee/tensorflow-to-solve-simple-math-equation-27f42a44f0f1).

When I run the following code, I get an error when executing the evaln line:

```
x = tf$constant(c(1.,2.))
y = tf$constant(c(12,4))
Z = tf$Variable(tf$zeros(2,1))
yy = tf$add(x, Z)
deviation = tf$square(y - yy)

opt = tf$optimizers$Adam(0.01)

evaln = compile(object = yy, optimizer = opt, loss = deviation)
```

> Error in UseMethod("compile") : 
>     no applicable method for 'compile' applied to an object of class "c('tensorflow.tensor', 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor', 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops._EagerTensorBase', 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor', 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_like._TensorLike', 'python.builtin.object')

I can guess that the error means I need to pass tensorflow model class object to "object" parameter in "compile" function but I have not been able to figure how to solve this. Anyone has an idea how this can be done in R using TensorFlow.